# Use interface as a swagger schema - NestJS DTO

Tags: swagger, nestjs, swagger-ui

I have the following code:

```
import { IsNotEmpty, IsArray, ArrayMinSize } from 'class-validator';
import { ApiProperty } from '@nestjs/swagger';

export class PublishDto {
  @IsNotEmpty()
  @IsArray()
  @ArrayMinSize(1)
  @ApiProperty({
    type: [Product]
  })
  products: Product[];
}

interface Product {
  id: string;
  title: string;
  sku: string;
  stock: number;
  description: string;
  shortDescription: string;
  imagesUrl: string[];
  price: number;
  department: string;
  category: string;
  brand: string;
  keywords: string[];
  isActive: boolean;
}
```

[image]

I'm trying to put the interface *`Product`* as a schema on swagger, but it's not working, I am getting an error.
Any idea?

Comment: What's the error that you're getting?

Comment: I'm getting an error on the code. It doesn't compile, because the type attribute is not accepting the Product interface. If you take a look at the image I uploaded, you'll see the error on ApiProperty.

Comment: I can see that there's a red line indicating that there is an error. Please share the actual text of the error

Comment: this error: error TS2693: 'Product' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The type property is expecting a value that is available at runtime, for example an actual Class or the Javascript `String` type. Interfaces exist only at compile time and so they aren't valid to be passed in this way.

You'll have to convert it to a Class if you want to pass it manually otherwise you could take a look at using the NestJS Swagger compiler plugin which uses some cool compile-time magic to automatically try and figure some of this stuff out for you

Comment: Unless i'm missing something, even with Swagger-CLI (the plugin made by Nest to like automatically use DTOs and stuff in routes), it still doesn't work with interface

Comment: It can't work with Interfaces, they don't exist at runtime.

Comment: Okay that's what i understood. Your sentence "You'll have to convert it to a Class" [...] "otherwhise you could take a look at using the NestJS Swagger" is kinda misleading to me, make is sound like it would work with it to me.